# Nginx reverse proxy SSL using different domain on each side

Tags: nginx, ssl, vpn, proxy, domain

I need a little tip on how to solve a setup I came across where client wants to access an HTTPs API hosted on **api.foo.com** (our domain, with ***.foo.com** certificate) using **api.bar.com** (client's domain name).

The request is routed through a point to point VPN from their infrastructure to ours using internal static IP addressing.

So client makes a request on their side to **https://api.bar.com** and reaches an static IP on our side of the tunnel where we have put a reverse proxy using nginx that forwards that request to **https://api.foo.com**

In this scenario, proxy responses have CN=***.foo.com** and since client expects ***.bar.com** TLS handshake fails on verifying ownership.

The only solutions I've thought is to:

1. Do not use HTTPs between client and proxy, relying security on the VPN itself
2. Use client certificate on our side proxy, but that will require to request their private key to make that setup, and seems wrong from obvious reasons.

Any help that can shed some light is welcome,

thank you!

Comment: How many devices/users at the client site are accessing your API?  Is the current certificate from a commercial CA or from a corporate/internal CA?

Comment: At the client side we don't know, probably the will access our API from one single point.
The current certificate is issued by Amazon (our infrastructure is on aws)

Comment: Can you explain more details of the "reverse proxy" you have set up?

Comment: It's just a simple stream with proxy_pass listening on port 443, it has nothing fancy

Comment: The problem here is that your CA has certified you as __foo.com__ only, but your client is accessing you with the incorrect name (__bar.com__).  Why can't the client access you by your correct name in the 1st place?

Comment: Exactly! and the API we are providing is already publicly accessible! they requested as mandatory to access through private VPN and through a domain of it's own, that's why I'm lost, I guess It has something to do with their security compliance but It's something I've never seen. I don't think that I can deploy a service on our side answering HTTPs requests for a domain we don't own without been insecure by nature... that's why I'm asking if someone has faced a similar situation